# Trying to launch a Visual Studio C# program from inside another one

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I am having great difficulty getting a Windows program, written in VS 2008 C#, to launch another type program.  I've put a main program to offer you the ability to launch some other VS 2008 C# programs.  When one of them is selected the following code is intended to do the launch:

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Documents and Settings\rat\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\PV_002_082708\PV_001\PV_001\bin\Debug\PV.exe");

It works, but each user will have a different path.  The path shown is for my computer. The code would have to know where each persons program was installed! In the past, I could easily call a program that was in the C:\Program Files location because that's where the MS Package & Deployment program put the programs.  VS 2008/2010 doesn't put them there!

I'm sure I am not knowledgeable about Visual Studio 2008/2010 to know if there is a way around this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, Im not a 100%, but I'm pretty sure you would need to embedd the exe into the dll.  So that when you deploy it, its always looking at itself for the exe.

Comment: That's something I never thought about.  I see your other comment has a link to a discussion about it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.Io.Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "PV.exe"));
```

assuming that the program is in the launched application's path.

or...

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.Io.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), @"Visual Studio 2008\Projects\PV_002_082708\PV_001\PV_001\bin\Debug\PV.exe"));
```

assuming you want to open the project from it's place.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  I tried your first one and got error "The system cannot find the file specified".  The second one requires you to know what directory the file is on everyone's computer.  The first one would be great because it would not need the path.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the installation package you can set the install path to some fixed path that users will not be able to change and than use that from your code (not very user friendly but it would work) or insert the user chosen path value into the registry and get it from there instead.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about getting the hard path for all the users, but there are over 30 and each program that will be offered to launch has its own special path.  It is a real solution but I was trying to find a simpler way to do it.  Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

May want to have a look at this thread.  How-to as well as lots of pro's and cons.

[Embedded a *.exe into a dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573105/embedded-a-exe-into-a-dll)

If you see the first answer to his question, I think this would work for you.

Simply he is saying, you add a resource file to your project, then when the user runes your program, it extracts your exe file that you added as a resource file to somewhere you know on the end users maching.

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I am wondering if I imbed some exe progs into the resources, will this program have to be recompiled if any of the imbedded ones are changed?  Or will the resource hold just a link and all you have to do is recompile the program (outside the resource)? I hope I made sense.

Comment: Hello Bob, when you build your project, this is when the compiler adds these files to your assembly.  So everytime you update these external resources, I would think that you need to re-build your solution.