# Baking an external .exe into a C# project

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Embedded a *.exe into a dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573105/embedded-a-exe-into-a-dll)

I have a C# project - a class library - that produces a DLL file.

From within itself, this project runs an external .exe file. (Using the standard Process stuff, and it works fine.)

However, my question is: How can I bake the external .exe file into the project, such that the end-consumer will only receive the final DLL file, without ever seeing the .exe file itself?

This will make my client happier, as he will continue receiving one DLL file (as before, before I needed the .exe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your client needs the .exe at runtime, you'd darn well better make sure he has a copy of the .exe.  IMHO...

PS:

You can "trick" the client by embedding your .dll as a resource (as a "Trojan horse"), and then extracting it at runtime.  Which, IMHO, would be stupid.  Expensive.  And risky.

If you need the .exe, ship the .exe.  And be explicit about it.

If the client expressly refuses to have an .exe - then your implemention violates the requirements, and you need to go back to the drawing board.

The "exe-as-resource" workaround ... is a lie and a cheat.  And it isn't even a very efficient or safe cheat.

ALSO:

> [Embedded a *.exe into a dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573105/embedded-a-exe-into-a-dll)
>
> On a side note, remember that when you pull a file from your resources
>   to disk and then execute code on it, you may trigger Windows Data
>   Execution Prevention - basically, Windows tries to automatically
>   detect if something is supposed to be code or data, and if it looks
>   like data (which a resource would), then it will prevent that data
>   from being executed as code.
>
> This becomes a particularly sticky issue if your .NET assembly is
>   going to be used over a network instead of from a local drive - there
>   are all sorts of .NET security configurations that might prevent this
>   from working correctly.

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to launch it as an external process, it needs to exist on disk.  It could be embedded in the .dll as a resource and extracted on-demand.

Comment: Which, of course, is sheer craziness.

Comment: I'm not advocating it, just identifying constraints and possible solutions.

Comment: In that spirit, you're 100% correct.  Thank you for your positive contribution.  Sincerely .. Paulsm

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to make the exe an [embedded resource](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292).